# Find time complexity of a code that runs three loops

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I have this piece of code and I would like to find its time complexity. I am preparing for interviews and I think this one is a bit tough.

```
int foo (int n) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    int k, i, j;
    int t = 2;

    for (i=n/2; i>0; i/=2)
    {
        for(j=0; j<i; j++) 
        { 
            for(k=0; k<log2(t-1); k++) 
            {
                sum += bar(sum);
                // bar time-complexity for all inputs is O(1)
            }
        }
        t = pow(2, i);
    }
}
```

---

I don't know why but I am unable to bound this expression and find a complexity.

Any help on how to resolve this ?

Comment: The `t = pow(2, t)` means that the number of innermost loops increases *very* quickly: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Examples and note how large the jump from 4 to 5 iterations is. This means that the last term in the outer loop is going to dominate, because this function grows *much* faster than exponential decrease of `i`. Thus the complexity is `O(2 ↑↑ [log n - 1])` in Knuth's notation.

Comment: Are you sure it is `pow(2, t)` and not `pow(t, 2)` and you miss-clicked it ?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: `t` increases quickly; log2(t) less so.  I believe that the problem is non-trivial, but tractable.

Comment: @prune the logarithm of a repeated exponential is only one step behind the exponential itself

Comment: I'm sorry, its i not t

Comment: I solved it yesterday for i and not t in the pow function. Let me reedit my answer and undelete it.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I worked it out over the weekend.  I got what you and Tony discussed in the chat room.  I had a nice attack, but the problem is *not* tractable in a classic sense: no readily derivable closed-form expression.

Comment: @Prune indeed; turns out the OP meant `i` after all, but it was still an interesting digression.

Answer (score 3):

Lets write it down as:

```
(n/2)*log(1) + (n/4)*log(3) + ... + 1*(log(n-1)). Which is equal to:
```

[image]

```
< n * [log(2^i)/(2^i) for i in range 1...n] .
= n * [log(2)/2 + log(4)/4 + log(8)/8 + ... + log(n)/n)]
```

This yeilds to `O(n)`

Comment: Note `t = pow(2, t)`, not `pow(2, i)`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog look at the formula, then I rewritten it with the sigma, and only then I worked on i.

Comment: Are you sure? Why `1 / 2^i`? I tested this code in Javascript, and as soon as `n = 32` there is double precision overflow. So there is no way it can be O(n)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, yes because first iteration it runs `n/2` times for `log(1)`. Then it runs `n/4` times for `log(3)`. 3rd time it runs `n/8` for `log(7)`.

Comment: no, 3rd time it runs for `log(2^2^2 - 1) = log(15)`; 4th time it runs for `log(2^2^2^2-1) = log(2^16-1) =log(65535)`. As I stressed before this is because `t = pow(2, t)`. Write some code and test it for yourself.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog do you agree on answer too :) ? I am still hesitating that I might have missed something.

Comment: No, there is no closed form for this solution. Even Euler was not able to get much further than merely finding *where* this function diverges. It can't be decomposed into a simple product like this. See http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheRepeatedPowerFunction/

Comment: No, as I've repeatedly tried to explain, it is *not* a simple exponential function - it is a *repeated* exponential function, one of the form 2^2^2^2^2 .. `i - 1` times. It cannot be described by such a simple form (not to mention that it grows *much much faster* than `2^n`)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog time to ask OP from what book is this question then.

Comment: I think the issue is a misunderstanding of *exponent laws*: you may be thinking that because 2^2 = 2*2, that 2^2^2 = 2*2*2, 2^2^2^2 = 2*2*2*2, etc. and hence your answer of 2^n

Comment: @meowgoesthedog nope..
Look at the iterations. `2` `2*2` `2*2*2*2` `2^16`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I am multiplying `2` `2^i` times, and not `i` times.

Comment: But that is only the *next* step of the iteration you have there (2^2^i); what about the next? and the next? Simple multiplying will not do the trick here. I'm not trying to be rude, but please do some reading on power laws and look again carefully at how `t` increases. Write some code to test it and hopefully you'll immediately find that `t` grows *much* faster than any simple multiple of `2^i` (or 2^2^i) for that matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150446/discussion-between-tony-tannous-and-meowgoesthedog).

Answer (score 3):

Since you've shown no progress, I'll give you top-level hints:

- let log_t = log2(t).  What is log_t as a function of i?
- Note that the outer loop is executed log2(n) times.
- How many *total* times is the `j` loop executed?
- Pick a sample value of `n`, such as 32.  For each value of `i`, how many times is the `sum +=` statement executed?  Can you generalize an equation for this based on `n`?